# How can I send karate html or XML reports to customized folder based on the tags

Tags: xml, jenkins, report, karate

I want to generate custom folder for karate html/XML reports based on the tag. So Jenkins would be taking reports from that folder and publish to a dashboard categorized based on tags. I am thinking we can pass the tags in vmargs to Jenkins and the target path to get the reports.
So the end goal would be for each tag, there would be a seperate Jenkins job and we don't have to change anything later.

Comment: please assume that this is not supported by karate. refer linked answer as to how you can write your own report. you are most welcome to contribute code to karate

Comment: Okay thanks @PeterThomas I can try that. Do you have any idea how can we achieve this?

Comment: Did you read the information given in the link ?